# Polarization by scattering - Gas dependence

Tags: optics, scattering

It is known that the sunlight that traverses the atmosphere is scattered. The scattered light is polarized, particularly if we look perpendicularly to the light's direction.

All the explanations I can find on this phenomenon involve some dipole. E.g. to quote E. Hecht - Optics:

> The orientation of the electric field of the scattered radiation $\vec{E}_s$ follows the dipole pattern such that $\vec{E}_s$, the Poynting vector $\vec{S}$ and the oscillating dipole are coplanar.

Now my question is: the dipole behavior of the air molecules depend on the fact that they are mostly diatomic, and thus electrons have a preferred direction to oscillate, or it's something much more general? In other words, what would happen if I were to replace all oxygen and nitrogen in the air with helium, or methane? Would the light scattered still be polarized?

Comment: Lyman α photons (i.e. λ = 1216 Å) scattering off of atomic hydrogen in the ground (1S) state (which is "spherically symmetric") may be polarized, depending on the angle of scattering.

Comment: @pela: Now that you mention it, I remember I heard this information in an astronomy lecture. But still, is the effect weaker because of the spherical symmetry, or does the shape of the scatterer have nothing to do with this phenomenon?

Comment: For large scattering agents, such as dust grains, the shape matters. For atoms and molecules I don't know in general, but I know that for Lyman α you can have 100% polarization if the photon scatters off by 90º. So, I can't give you a good answer, but I can say that at least in this case, you can have a large degree of polarization from a symmetric particle.

Comment: You can also have polarization from Thomson scattering, i.e. off free electrons which are also symmetric particles.